# image button in list view that is derived using sherlock list fragment

Tags: android

I want to use **image button** in list view that is derived using **sherlock list fragment** when i click the button in the list..then i want show a dialog fragment..for this i want the syntax..
My Xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/manage_stocks"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lysymbol"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lname"
    android:layout_below="@id/lname"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/alertbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/alerts"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

some body help me to do this task

Thanks for any help in future..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) to see how to implement a custom DialogFragment.